# Using jQuery 1.7 .on() and event.stopPropagation to close boxes when clicking in document body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

I have the following code which works but seems like it could be improved. I'm not sure if I'm using `event.stopPropagation()` correctly or if it is the best solution.

The elements are loaded via AJAX and so need to have `.on()` (previously `.live()`, which is now deprecated in jQuery 1.7).

I've used the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/153047#153047) as a basis.

```
$('html').on('click', '.poster:not(.active) .image-effect', function (event) {

        var obj = $(this).parent();

        // If there are no .close spans
        if (obj.find('.close').length === 0) {

            // Add the close element by javascript to remain semantic
            obj.find('.quick-view').append('<span class="close">&times;</span>');
        }

        // Close any open Quick Views
        closeQuickView();

        // Add the active class (controls opacity)
        obj.addClass('active');

        // Fade in the Quick View
        obj.find('.quick-view').fadeIn(200, 'easeInOutQuint');

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

    });

    $('html').on('click', '.active', function () {
        return false;
    });

    $('html').on('click', '.close', function () {
        closeQuickView();
    });

    $('html').on('click', '.quick-view', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Close the QuickView with a button
    $('html').on('click', function () {
        closeQuickView();
    });

    function closeQuickView() {
        $('.poster').removeClass('active');
        $('.quick-view').fadeOut(200, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }
```

For some reason clicking the document isn't working in Chrome (the `closeQuickView` is not being called) which may be an indicator that the code is not functioning 100%.

My markup is as follows:

```
<figure class="grid_2 box poster">
    <a class="image-effect" href="#">
        <img class="colour" src="path/to/image" />
        <img class="bw" src="path/to/image" />
    </a>
    <div class="quick-view">

        Content

    </div>
</figure>
```

Is this the right way to approach the scenario? Are there any conflicting functions?

Comment: Actually, you are not using `on` instead of `live`, but instead of `delegate`.

Comment: Oh, really? Ok. I got a little confused as the .on() function in 1.7 seems to do the job of a few things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did work in my Chrome. However, I felt your code was confusing with all those handlers. Let me suggest the following:

```
$('html').on('click', '.poster', function(e) {

  var target = $(e.target);
  var poster = $(this);      

  if (!poster.hasClass('active')) {
    closeQuickView();
    poster.addClass('active').find('.quick-view').fadeIn(200);
  }
  if (target.hasClass('quick-view') || target.hasClass('image-effect')) e.stopPropagation(); // prevent bubbling and thus closeClickView call below
});

$('html').on('click', closeQuickView);
```

This way, it's more concise and hopefully clearer what's handling what.

PS: I threw out the conditional '.close' appendage here, nothing wrong with having it in the vanilla HTML I'd say.

Comment: I understand it but would not have been able to write it as succinctly. The reason for appending the spans was to maintain semantic code. Thanks!